# Do something when no motion detected in Hue

Tags: philips-hue

Is there a way to turn on a device (a hue smart plug in this case) when the hue motion sensor detects no more motion?

We have a fan that is like to be on when the room is empty, but off if anyone walks in the room

Comment: Haven’t tried it, but IFTTT maybe? Otherwise this can be done programmatically by polling the sensor state via the API.

Comment: Bwaaaa IFTTT apparently does not support any trigger from Hue. Probably because Hue lacks any form of push or callback. So you're left to use a device somewhere to poll the Hue bridge for the motion sensor status and act accordingly, I guess. You'll need a server somewhere (either on your network or in the cloud) to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The [Three Times is a Charm](https://labs.meethue.com/formulas/huelabs/three-times-is-a-charm) formula from Hue Labs appears to be the answer (emphasis mine):

> Imagine you’re relaxing on the couch watching your favorite series, and suddenly the lights turn off because you are sitting still. With this Formula this situation belongs to the past, as it introduces an additional evening slot for your Hue motion sensor, on top of the day and night setting. You can choose your favorite scene or select ‘do nothing’ when there is motion, and **choose what to do when there is no motion**.

It appears that you can select the scene you want when there is no motion:

[image]